# run a script every time a bluetooth device get connected

Tags: scripts, keyboard, bluetooth

Every time my bluetooth keyboard connects to my desktop, the system turns on the num-lock.
How can I run a script every time a bluetooth device get connected?

This way I could

```
#!/bin/bash    
sleep 0.01 
numlockx off
return 0
```

and stop thinking to this issue.

Thank you.